# Removing footer data from Server

Tags: centos, postgresql-9.1, openerp-7

I have installed OpenERP in Server and i am not able to remove "Powered By OpenERP" which is present in Footer. I tried many methods like i changed the file content, replaced the file, gave permission to the file. But the data which we are giving is not taking. But if i try in localhost it works fine.
This CSS is taking in local, but not taking in server.
    .openerp .oe_footer a span {
      color: #c81010;
      display:none;
    }

[image]

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/Help-1/question/Is-it-allowed-to-remove-the-OpenERP-logo-and-footer-1908

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **7.0**. This `Powered by OpenerERP` comes from the this file

```
7.0-web => addons => web => static => src => xml => base.xml
```

Now Search this tag `<div class="oe_secondary_menus_container"/>`.

Comment below the code.

```
<!--div class="oe_footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank">
    <span>OpenERP</span></a>
</div-->
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried that it is working in localhost:8069 by if i put it in server it is not working. Can you please help me in this issue.

Comment: server ? I don't think so it doesn't work their. May be issue of putting the code in wrong path. Otherwise it will work. Please check out `web path` that `server or instance` run.

Comment: This is the URL http://103.15.234.152:8069 Can you please tell me the web path! because when i searched it was showing same file, i edited css file also but it didnt worked.

Comment: No need to edit in `css file`, Just remove above whole `<div> tag` from the above path file.

Comment: No use Odedra, may i'm doing corrections in wrong path

Comment: I think same also. It's work on locally because you know the correct path. Now in server, you don't know the correct path weather your web put. So first ask him/her to directly where is web ? This will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting -> Technical -> User Interface -> Views
Search : "**menu_secondary**"
you fine : **web.menu_secondary**, click to edit,
You can remove or edit "oe_footer" class and save:

```
<div class="oe_footer">
      Powered by <a href="http://www.odoo.com" target="_blank"><span>Odoo</span></a>
</div>
```